# A valid JSON string throws JSONException with null Exception variable

Tags: android, wcf, rest

My system based on an android client and a wcf - rest - web service.
I'm using this tutorial: http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx
I'm having a weird problem. I have a valid JSON string (checked it with online tools), the reading to the buffer goes well but when I'm trying to create a JSON array it throws JSONException without an exception variable (the variable is NULL - never happend to me before)
The line that throws the excption:

```
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

            JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
```

the last line throws the exception.

The text from the service is this:
[{"dtFromDate":"1899-12-30 20:00:00","fBuyWindow":120,"fNewPrice":150,"fOldPrice":400,"lLatitude":32.021327,"lLongitude":34.776452,"nDestinatedPlatform":1,"nMessageID":1,"nRange":5,"nStickingHours":48,"strDetailedDescription":"נעלי נייק מסוג N95, הנעליים של לאונל מסי, בהנחה מטורפת.","strDisplayAddress":"חנקין 49, חולון","strFullAddress":"חנקין 49, חולון, ישראל","strImagePath":"http://images.free-extras.com/pics/n/nike_swoosh-703.jpg","strItemDescrpition":"נעלי נייק דגם N95 לבן","strThumbPath":"http://images.free-extras.com/pics/n/nike_swoosh-703.jpg","strTitle":"נייק קניון חולון"},{"dtFromDate":"1899-12-30 20:00:00","fBuyWindow":120,"fNewPrice":150,"fOldPrice":400,"lLatitude":32.021327,"lLongitude":34.776452,"nDestinatedPlatform":1,"nMessageID":2,"nRange":5,"nStickingHours":48,"strDetailedDescription":"נעלי נייק מסוג N95, הנעליים של לאונל מסי, בהנחה מטורפת.","strDisplayAddress":"","strFullAddress":"חנקין 49, חולון, ישראל","strImagePath":"","strItemDescrpition":"נעלי נייק דגם N95 לבן","strThumbPath":"","strTitle":"נייק קניון חולון"},{"dtFromDate":"1899-12-30 20:00:00","fBuyWindow":120,"fNewPrice":150,"fOldPrice":400,"lLatitude":32.021327,"lLongitude":34.776452,"nDestinatedPlatform":1,"nMessageID":3,"nRange":5,"nStickingHours":48,"strDetailedDescription":"נעלי נייק מסוג N95, הנעליים של לאונל מסי, בהנחה מטורפת.","strDisplayAddress":"","strFullAddress":"חנקין 49, חולון, ישראל","strImagePath":"","strItemDescrpition":"נעלי נייק דגם N95 לבן","strThumbPath":"","strTitle":"נייק קניון חולון"},{"dtFromDate":"1899-12-30 20:00:00","fBuyWindow":120,"fNewPrice":150,"fOldPrice":400,"lLatitude":32.021327,"lLongitude":34.776452,"nDestinatedPlatform":1,"nMessageID":4,"nRange":5,"nStickingHours":48,"strDetailedDescription":"נעלי נייק מסוג N95, הנעליים של לאונל מסי, בהנחה מטורפת.","strDisplayAddress":"","strFullAddress":"חנקין 49, חולון, ישראל","strImagePath":"","strItemDescrpition":"נעלי נייק דגם N95 לבן","strThumbPath":"","strTitle":"נייק קניון חולון"},{"dtFromDate":"1899-12-30 20:00:00","fBuyWindow":120,"fNewPrice":150,"fOldPrice":400,"lLatitude":32.021327,"lLongitude":34.776452,"nDestinatedPlatform":1,"nMessageID":5,"nRange":5,"nStickingHours":48,"strDetailedDescription":"נעלי נייק מסוג N95, הנעליים של לאונל מסי, בהנחה מטורפת.","strDisplayAddress":"","strFullAddress":"חנקין 49, חולון, ישראל","strImagePath":"","strItemDescrpition":"נעלי נייק דגם N95 לבן","strThumbPath":"","strTitle":"נייק קניון חולון"}]

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the string you are getting. Are you sure 'plates' is a JSON array and not a JSON object.

Comment: My guess is that it's a character encoding problem. From what I can see in that JSON string there are Hebrew characters - am I correct? Using `char[]` for your buffer and then `new String(buffer)` when creating the `JSONArray` won't work. You need to use `UTF-8` encoding and a `ByteStream` I think.

Comment: You right. Hebrew characters. I'll try that and tell you in a couple of hours. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you please direct me how to implement the cast with the classes u mentioned?

Comment: Forget what I said about using ByteStream - I was mistaken. See my answer below, I think it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

Change this line...

```
char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
```

...to use a byte array as follows...

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
```

You'll have to forget about using `InputStreamReader` as it only works with `char[]`. Instead read the stream using...

```
stream.read(buffer);
```

Then change this line...

```
JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
```

...to this to create a UTF-8 encoded String...

```
JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: That works great! thanks ALOT!
I have a tiny problem now - it seems like there's a limitation of 2000 characters on HTTP GET protocol. Do you have any idea how to change the limitation / work with another protocol at the client side?

Comment: @Shahar: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean the GET request (URL) is limited to 2000 characters? Or the amount that can be downloaded is limited? There is no limit to the download size that I know of - my app downloads files which are several MB in size for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
String newString = reader.read(buffer); //assuming you only get one line in response, rather than many (add a loop if so)
JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(newString);
```

That may help. Otherwise, here is some JSON related coding that I've done that ends up using a JSONArray:

```
public JSONArray getQuestionsJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {  
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        String jsonData = reader.readLine();
        JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        is.close();
        return jarr;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```